# Short Order on Binance futures testnet resulting in APIError (ReduceOnly Order is Rejected)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptocurrency, binance, binance-api-client

On using futures testnet API through python-binance library: https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance

I am getting this in ‘Buy Short’ in Hedge mode. I am able to execute the same order via the UI and it works. I am able to use the API for ‘Buy Long’ orders successfully.
Here is my code sample:

```
short_order={      "symbol":"BTCUSDT",
            "side": "BUY",
            "type": "MARKET",
            "positionSide" : "SHORT",
            "quantity": "0.001"}
res = client.futures_create_order(**short_order)
print(res)
```

Getting this response:
BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-2022): ReduceOnly Order is rejected.

Is there something that I’m doing wrong to place the Short order. Reduce-only parameter is mentioned that it is not used in Hedge mode according to API docs.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured the problem. The side needs to be 'SELL' to short.

Answer (score 0):

The "Position Side" need to be BOTH (Buy/Sell is for reduce existing order only).

Then the "Side" Buy for LONG and Sell for SHORT.